# How can I get a value corresponding to the maximum average in this SQL exercise?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to solve this exercise, but I'm stuck when it comes to show the **CCode** where I have the maximum average of students.
I attach the pic of the exercise and the database tables.
Thanks in advance.[image: database]
[image: enter image descriptioexercise here]

Here's my code:

```
SELECT CO.TCode, CO.CCode
FROM COURSE CO
WHERE CO.CCode NOT IN(
  SELECT CCode
  FROM COURSE
  WHERE Topic <> 'database')
AND CO.CCode =(
  SELECT C1.CCode
  FROM (SELECT CCode, AVG(AttendingStudent#) MEDIA
       FROM LECTURE
       GROUP BY CCode) C1
  WHERE MAX(C1.MEDIA) AND C1.CCode = CO.CCode
)
```

I don't think the **maximum** in the **WHERE** clause can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can order the subquery and use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` to get the maximum (or `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` if there would be join highest, but then you would need to change from an `=` comparison to `IN`).

```sql
SELECT CO.TCode,
       CO.CCode
FROM   COURSE CO
WHERE  CO.CCode NOT IN( SELECT CCode
                        FROM   COURSE
                        WHERE  Topic <> 'database')
AND    CO.CCode = ( SELECT c.CCode
                    FROM   Course c
                           INNER JOIN LECTURE l
                           ON (c.ccode = l.ccode)
                    WHERE  l.TCode = CO.TCode 
                    GROUP BY CCode
                    ORDER BY AVG(AttendingStudent#) DESC
                    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
                  )
```

Otherwise, you can use a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT CO.TCode,
       CO.CCode
FROM   COURSE CO
WHERE  CO.CCode NOT IN( SELECT CCode
                        FROM   COURSE
                        WHERE  Topic <> 'database'
                      )
AND    CO.CCode IN ( SELECT CCode
                     FROM (
                       SELECT TCode,
                              CCode,
                              AVG(AttendingStudent#) MEDIA
                       FROM   LECTURE
                       GROUP BY TCode, CCode
                     ) C1
                     WHERE  c1.TCode = CO.TCode
                     HAVING c1.MEDIA = MAX(C1.MEDIA)
                   )
```

*Note: Your first sub-query is not correct as you want to find the teacher that has not taught a non-databases course and not the non-databases courses. It's almost correct though as you only need to change the column you are comparing on but I am sure you can correct it.*

Comment: so is it possible inserting the HAVING clause even not right after the GROUP BY clause??

Comment: last question, (it's more an advice) how can I imagine the nested query that you wrote FROM (
                       SELECT TCode,
                              CCode,
                              AVG(AttendingStudent#) MEDIA
                       FROM   LECTURE
                       GROUP BY TCode, CCode
                     ) C1
                     WHERE  c1.TCode = CO.TCode
                     HAVING c1.MEDIA = MAX(C1.MEDIA)
                   ) because it's difficult for me to understand when it comes to the where that joins the inner table to the outer. Thank you!

Comment: @Sebastian Regarding your first question, if you use aggregation functions without a `GROUP BY` clause then you are effectively saying that everything is in one group. If you use a `GROUP BY` clause then that defines how you separate the rows up into multiple different groups.

Comment: Regarding your second question, nested queries are not joins. Imagine you have a set of results and you preform the operations from the inner-most sub-query and get the results from that then you apply the operations from the next sub-query and get the results from that .... and so on if you have more layers of sub-queries. They are not joins to different results sets but sequences of operations to perform on the same result set.

Comment: in the code you wrote, putting "c1.MEDIA = MAX(C1.MEDIA)" in the WHERE clause, instead of the HAVING, is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following as subquery:

```
SELECT C1.CCode
FROM (SELECT CCode, 
             AVG(AttendingStudent#) MEDIA
       FROM LECTURE
       GROUP BY CCode) C1
GROUP BY C1.CCode
HAVING MAX(C1.MEDIA) AND C1.CCode = CO.CCode
```

You will be aggregating on "*C1.MEDIA*" and grouping on "*C1.CCode*", but the aggregation will just happen inside the `HAVING` clause, leaving only the codes for selection.

Some tips on how to use the `HAVING` clause [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_group_by_having.htm).